# How to do a line insensitive difference (diff) in linux?

Tags: linux, diff

I have two text files where the order of lines does not matter. I want to find out the lines that are different in one file to the other. Using diff in linux finds the difference but also accounts for the change in the lines of the same text.

In other words, How do I do a line insensitive difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your files are not too large, you can `sort` them before `diff`ing.

So something like this would work:

```
sort file1 > file1_sorted
sort file2 > file2_sorted
diff file1_sorted file2_sorted
```

Or, as you have found out in the comments, you can also do it in one line,

```
diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the `diff` options you could use the `comm` command with the process substitutions and `sort` (`comm` requires the files it operates on be sorted).  This would let you focus on just the common lines, just the lines that are in one file or the other by using `-1` to supress lines only in the first file, `-2` to suppress lines only in the second file or `-3` to suppress lines in both, so to see all lines that are only in the first file and not the second you could do

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

of course, if you want that you could also consider using `grep` like

```
grep -vFxf file2 file1
```

which will treat the lines in `file2` as patterns and only print the lines from file1 which have no matches (`-v`) when treating the lines from (`-f`) `file2` as fixed strings (`-F`) that must match the entire line (`-x`).

The `grep` solution has the advantage of not needing to sort the files, but it only checks for lines in one of the files that are not in the other, not in both directions at once.

Comment: I'd emphasize that `comm` needs **sorted** files. (Yes, you mention it indirectly, but it's easy to overlook the way you have phrased it). Also, `comm` is much more efficient for this scenario than `diff`. The `grep` solution can easily run out of memory if `file2` is large (exponential blowup when converting the NFA to a DFA), we had a question about this not long ago.